# Name Lookup and class scope

Tags: c++, c++11, scope, name-lookup, class-members

Why is it that the return type of setVal is of type string and the parameter type is of type double

```
typedef string Type;
Type initVal(); 
class Exercise {
public:
    typedef double Type;
    Type setVal(Type); 
    Type initVal(); 
private:
    int val;
};

Type Exercise::setVal(Type parm) {  
    val = parm + initVal();    
    return val;
}
```

Comment: Note that you have two unrelated `setVal` in your program.

Comment: @cpplearner The first setVal is the declaration the second is the definition.

Comment: The second would need to be `Exercise::setVal` to be a definition of the class's function. By itself that `setVal` is a free function completely separate from the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When member functions are defined in namespace scope C++ provides special name lookup rules for unqualified names that *follow* the function’s *declarator-id* (3.4.1/8). Such names are looked up in class scope before they are looked up in namespace scope.

Since the return type in an "ordinary" member function definition *precedes* function’s *declarator-id*, the aforementioned special rules do not apply to it. It is looked up in accordance with the "usual" rules: in namespace scope.

For this reason your function definition's return type refers to `::Type`, not to `Exercise::Type`. It does not match any of the declarations made inside the class. The code is ill-formed.

If you want the unqualified return type name to be looked up in class scope as well, use the new *trailing return type* syntax in function declaration, since in this syntax the return type *follows* function’s *declarator-id*

```
auto Exercise::setVal(Type parm) -> Type {  
    val = parm + initVal();    
    return val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That code doesn't compile, and I'm having trouble teasing out what it's supposed to do, but I think the answer to your question is that the parameter is of type `Exercise::Type`, while the return value is of type `::Type`, the global typedef. If you want them to match, when you define `setVal` outside the class definition, you need to fully specify the return value as `Exercise::Type`, as so:

```
typedef string Type;

class Exercise {
public:
    typedef double Type;
    Type setVal(Type);
    Type initVal() { return 1.0; }
private:
    int val;
};

Exercise::Type Exercise::setVal(Type parm) {
    val = parm + initVal();
    return val;
}
```

Comment: Lets say the return type is just Type, if the function defines a function within the class why doesn't the return type look for declarations of type inside the class definition instead of the global scope?

Comment: @TheEnigma It's more or less just how names are scoped. From 9.9/1 in the standard: "Type names obey exactly the same scope rules as other names. In particular, type names defined within a class definition cannot be used outside their class without qualification." I guess this is mostly a question of how scope works for classes (specifically return value declarations). You could call it a quirk. Once you define the body of the method outside the class definition, the compiler searches for the return value from global (or whatever) scope. [Example](http://ideone.com/VYTfhx)

Comment: @The Enigma: Because the language name lookup rules say so.

Answer (score -1):

Because local variable will cover global variable automatically.